# Induction from normal subgroup, problem with degrees

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, representation-theory

Suppose $K$ is an arbitrary field, $G$ a finite group and $N$ a normal subgroup. If one know all the irreducible representations of $N$ and then form the induced representations, one can use Mackey maschine to check if they are irreducible or not.

**Question 1:**
Is this enough to get all the irreducible representations of $G$, or does one have to take also other subgroups? Why?

I tried to use this method in this example: [induced representation, dihedral group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133611/induced-representation-dihedral-group)
$K=\mathbb{Q}$, $G=D_p$ and $N=C_p$. I found out that $N$ has two irreducible representations (the trivial and one $p-1$ dimensional). Then I took the $p-1$ dimensional to induce it to a representation of $G$ and checked with Mackey maschine that it remains irreducible. But according to frobenius reciprocity it should have the degree $(p-1) \cdot [G:N] = 2(p-1)$, and not $p-1$ like in the post.

**Question 2:**
Why does induction don't work here? According to the post $G$ should have tree irreducible representations with dimensions 1, 1, p-1, and none of them with $2(p-1)$.

Best Regards

Comment: I think you made a mistake in your Mackey calculations: the induced rep. is not irreducible.

Comment: If I take the trivial representation of $C_p$ and induces it, I get a permutation representation with degree $[G:C_p]=2$. This must be reducible, so I get here 2 irreducible representations of $G$ both with degree 1.      If i take the $p-1$ dimensional representation and induced it, it must be irreducible, because $G$ has exactly 3 irreducible representations over $\mathbb{Q}$. I hope someone could find my mistake here.

Comment: Why can it not be a sum of the same two representations? (In fact - though I haven't checked - I think this is the case).

Comment: Ok, thank you, I will check my Mackey calculation again. But suppose I will get, that the $p-1$ dimensional decomposes into 2 irreducible representations. How do I know which degrees they have and how they decompose?

Comment: No, the induced rep. has degree $2(p-1)$, and it is not irreducible.  You cannot get the degree-$(p-1)$ rep. of $G$ by inducing from $N$. What you get is a multiple of that irreducible rep. though.

Comment: I think I unterstood it now. Thank you. Maybe you could copy your comments into the answer, so that I could accept it?

Comment: Actually, I think it would be better if *you* wrote up an answer, and accepted it! This way the question doesn't remain unanswered, you get a chance to put your understanding to the test, and if there are any errors, someone will correct you.  Everybody wins!

Comment: @SteveD It seems the OP won't convert the comments to an answer. Please consider converting them into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Answer (score 1):

As requested:

The induced representation cited in the question is not irreducible, but rather a multiple of an irreducible character.  In fact, the induced representation has degree $2(p-1)$, and is the sum of two copies of the $(p-1)$-degree irreducible representation of $G$.